# How to keep the horizontal overlay area space constant while the contents are updated?

Tags: beamer, overlays

I have the following problem with overlays in LaTeX beamer. On the first slide I want to display

[image]

while the second slide should show

[image]

The difficulty is to achieve that the amount of space occupied by *3+4+5* is also reserved on the first slide even though *12* would actually need less space.

The MWE below does NOT solve this problem. Is there any solution?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame{
\uncover<1-2>{}
1+2+\alt<1>{12}{3+4+5}+6+7=28
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: An easy fix would be `\alt<1>{\phantom{3+}1\phantom{+5}}{3+4+5}`, but it works if and only if the first alternative wouldn't have two digits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand\centerin[2]{{%
\ifmmode\def\dollar{$}\else\def\dollar{}\fi
\settowidth{\dimen8}{\dollar#2\dollar}%
\makebox[\dimen8]{\dollar#1\dollar}}}

\def\altcenterin<#1>#2#3{\alt<#1>{\centerin{#2}{#3}}{#3}}

\begin{document}
\frame{


\uncover<1-2>{}
1+2+\altcenterin<1>{12}{3+4+5}+6+7=28
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use features of `beamer` and of `mathtools`, combined with `calc`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools,calc}

\newcommand<>\mathalt[2]{%
  \alt#3{\mathmakebox[\widthof{$#2$}]{#1}}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\uncover<1-2>{}
$1+2+\mathalt<1>{12}{3+4+5}+6+7=28$

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

First subframe:

[image]

Second subframe:

[image]

(The small difference is due just to the screen capture, sorry.)